# Security for Docker (bridge network)

Tags: linux, networking, security, docker, tcp

I am running Docker on Linux (Ubuntu). By default, it uses the `docker0` network.

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:52ff:feb8:84eb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
```

I am running many programs for development, often without any sort of additional network authentication.

How would I set up my network security so that my host machine can connect to these but other machines on my network (including other devices on my home/corporate LAN) cannot initiate TCP connections?

What would be the firewall? Is this iptables...or something else?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is try bind (no brige) the ip and port and protect the connection destined to your machine as a classical firewall

1. Bind ports

   `docker run -dit --name <container-name> -p 8080:80 <image>`
2. Protect you host/app access

   `iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`

   `iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.200.0/24 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP`

Comment: This requires that I have a certain set of known ports that I am accessing. There are some cases, e.g. passive FTP server, where this is not the case.